# Mouse parallax effect quite jittery

Tags: parallax

Does anyone uses [mouse-parallax.js](https://github.com/pipbeard/mouse-parallax)? I am finding the effect quite jittery, specially on Chome in Mac. Has anyone who uses this plugin experienced the same issue?